# Find specific word in array of strings

Tags: python

I have two lists, one with strings and another one with words to be found.

Lets say:

```
list1 = ['Hi I am Tayyab','I am a python programmer', 'I am new To python' ]

list2 = ['Tayyab','Programmer']
```

I want to check if list 1 contains the words present in `list2`.

If yes then return the complete string present in `list1`.

In the above case I want the first two items in `list1` to be returned because the first two items contain the words `'Tayyab'` and `'Programmer'`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: for l in list1:
    if l.__contains__("Tayyab"):
        print(l)
nothing much I have just tried To manually Input a word and find in list 1 and it gives the desired result, but I want to loop through list 2 automatically instead of manually giving input, in this case I have given input of 'Tayyab' @KlausD.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Add all information to the question by editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work. It creates a list of all the phrases that contain any of the words in your list.

```
list1=['Hi I am Tayyab','I am a python programmer', 'I am new To python' ]

list2=['Tayyab','Programmer']

result = []

for word in list2:
  for phrase in list1:
    if word.lower() in phrase.lower():
      result.append(phrase)

unique_result = set(result)
print(result)
print(unique_result)
```

The `set` method at the end is used to take unique values out of a list, in case you only want each phrase once.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a list comprehension with `str.casefold`:

```
res = [i for i in list1 if any(k.casefold() in i.casefold() for k in list2)]

print(res)

['Hi I am Tayyab', 'I am a python programmer']
```

Answer (score 0):

the most simple approach might be

```
>>> for word in list2:
...     for sentence in list1:
...         if word.lower() in sentence.lower():
...             print(sentence)
... 
Hi I am Tayyab
I am a python programmer
```